# Android context in multiplatform project

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

I wonder if is possible to access the Android context application in androidMain sourceSets with the kotlin-multiplatform plugin.

Here is the build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-multiplatform'

kotlin {
    targets {
        final def iOSTarget = System.getenv('SDK_NAME')?.startsWith("iphoneos")   \
                                ? presets.iosArm64 : presets.iosX64

        fromPreset(iOSTarget, 'iOS') {
            compilations.main.outputKinds('FRAMEWORK')
        }

        fromPreset(presets.jvm, 'android')
    }

    sourceSets {

        commonMain {
            kotlin.srcDir('src')
            dependencies {
                implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-common:$kotlin_version"
                // coroutine
                implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core-common:1.1.0"
            }
        }

        androidMain {
            dependencies {
                implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
                // Timber
                implementation "com.jakewharton.timber:timber:$timber_version"
                // coroutine
                implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.1.0"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried add the 'com.android.application' plugin into androidMain source, but the sync fails.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't believe you can.  I think you'll need to have an `actual` method in your `androidMain` code that does whatever work context is needed for.

Comment: I am refactoring my code. Before kotlin-multiplatform plugin I had a android module with actual and application context. I think so androidMain can be a bridge between commonMain and context application.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can.

In your `build.gradle` file you are not targeting android as such (*presets.android*) but the `jvm` (*presets.jvm*) and calling it android.

As it is now, what your build will generated is a `JAR` file not an `aar` file.

If you want to target android you have also to use the android gradle plugin. To be able to use the android framework from the androidMain folder, update your build.gradle file. Below an example:

```
apply plugin: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.multiplatform'
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName '1.0'
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
        }
    }

        // By default the android gradle plugin expects to find the kotlin source files in 
        // the folder `main` and the test in the folder `test`. This is to be able place 
        // the source code files inside androidMain and androidTest folders
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'src/androidMain/AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src/androidMain/kotlin']
            res.srcDirs = ['src/androidMain/res']
        }
        test {
            java.srcDirs = ['src/androidTest/kotlin']
            res.srcDirs = ['src/androidTest/res']
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation "com.jakewharton.timber:timber:$timber_version
}

kotlin {
    targets {
        final def iOSTarget = System.getenv('SDK_NAME')?.startsWith("iphoneos")   \
                                ? presets.iosArm64 : presets.iosX64

        fromPreset(iOSTarget, 'iOS') {
            compilations.main.outputKinds('FRAMEWORK')
        }

        fromPreset(presets.android, 'android')
    }
    sourceSets {
        commonMain {
            dependencies {
                implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-common:$kotlin_version"
                // coroutine
                implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core-common:1.1.0"
            }
        }
        androidMain {
            dependencies {
                api "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
            }
        }
    }
}

task buildiOSFramework(type: Sync) {

    final File frameworkDir = new File(buildDir, "xcode-frameworks")
    final String mode = project.findProperty("XCODE_CONFIGURATION")?.toUpperCase() ?: 'DEBUG'

    inputs.property "mode", mode
    dependsOn kotlin.targets.iOS.compilations.main.linkTaskName("FRAMEWORK", mode)

    from { kotlin.targets.iOS.compilations.main.getBinary("FRAMEWORK", mode).parentFile }
    into frameworkDir

    doLast {
        new File(frameworkDir, 'gradlew').with {
            text = "#!/bin/bash\nexport 'JAVA_HOME=${System.getProperty("java.home")}'\ncd '${rootProject.rootDir}'\n./gradlew \$@\n"
            setExecutable(true)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have the same problem, I don't know how to get the Android Application Context in the AndroidMain souce set. I need the context to create the SQLDriver for the Android app. How do you achieve that? 

If it is possible to show your kotlin code? it would be nice to see how you do that! Thank you in advance

Comment: Any ideas how I would keep my keep generating a JAR library, and pass in the context, but only for the android implementation?

Comment: I can't figure out how this answers the question